# Hide a column using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table created dynamically and I want to hide columns based on group.

But so far all I could do is to hide the `tableHeaders` instead. And I can hide the header but the input for data still there http://prntscr.com/hl5so6

**My question is:**

How can I hide the entire column with class `name = "DDA"` for example.

So instead of this: `$('.dda').hide();` I want something like: `$('.dda').hideColumn();` and `$('.dda').show();` to `$('.dda').showColumns();`

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    appendHeader();
    select();
    var amountOfDayEnds = parseInt($('#amountOfDayEnds').val());
    appendBody(amountOfDayEnds);


});

$('#group').change(function () {
   select();
});

//Change Header based on the select
function select() {
    var group = $('#group').val();
    var table = $('#dataTable');
    console.log(group);
    switch (group) {
        case "DDA":
            $('.mtg').hide();
            $('.sav').hide();
            $('.dda').show();
            break;
        case "SAV":
            $('.mtg').hide();
            $('.sav').show();
            $('.dda').hide();
            break;
        case "MTG":
            $('.mtg').show();
            $('.sav').hide();
            $('.dda').hide();
            break;
    }
}

//Append Header
function appendHeader() {
    var thead = '<thead>';
    thead += "<tr class='text-primary text-center'>";
    thead += '<th>Day</th>';
    thead += '<th class="dda">Type 400</th>';
    thead += '<th class="dda">Type 4044</th>';
    thead += '<th class="dda">Type 4045</th>';
    thead += '<th class="sav">Type 300</th>';
    thead += '<th class="sav">Type 310</th>';
    thead += '<th class="mtg">Type 700</th>';
    thead += '<th class="mtg">Type 710</th>';
    thead += '</tr>';
    thead += '</thead>';

    $('#dataTableHead').append(thead);
}
function appendBody(amountOfDayEnds) {
    var data = "";
    console.log(amountOfDayEnds);
    for(var i=1;i<=amountOfDayEnds;i++) {
        data += '<tr align="center" class="hover-table">';
        data += '<td>' + i + '</td>';
        for (var j = 0; j< 8;j++) {
            data += '<td>' + '<input class="text-center config-input amountOfAccounts" type="number" value="0" min="0" max="500" name="dataAccounts[]" data-error="Please, insert a value"  required></td>'
        }
        data += '</tr>';
    }
    $('#dataTableBody').append(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can always add those classes dynamicaly.
In my solution, I have declared classes into array, in TH I pass the valies and then adding this (little bit altered for e.g. styling purposes) class in iteration where td are generated.

then you can simply call a hide on it.

so the major changes are:

```
var classes = ["dda","dda","dda","sav","sav","mtg","mtg"];
```

then

```
thead += '<th class="'+classes[0]+'">(dda)Type 400</th>';
```

and then

```
for (var j = 0; j< 7;j++) {
            data += '<td class="'+classes[j]+'td">' + '<input class="text-center config-input amountOfAccounts" type="number" value="0" min="0" max="500" name="dataAccounts[]" data-error="Please, insert a value"  required></td>'
        }
```

and then I have added a dummy button:

```
<button onclick="$('.dda').hide(); $('.ddatd').hide();">HIDE DDA</button>
```

I have also altered generating THEAD as you havent provided any source, and I believe all labels should be over correct column, so look at it too...

heres a solution:

```js
   $(document).ready(function () {
    appendHeader();
    //select();
    var amountOfDayEnds = 3;
    appendBody(amountOfDayEnds);


});

$('#group').change(function () {
   select();
});

//Change Header based on the select
function select() {
    var group = $('#group').val();
    var table = $('#dataTable');
    console.log(group);
    switch (group) {
        case "DDA":
            $('.mtg').hide();
            $('.sav').hide();
            $('.dda').show();
            break;
        case "SAV":
            $('.mtg').hide();
            $('.sav').show();
            $('.dda').hide();
            break;
        case "MTG":
            $('.mtg').show();
            $('.sav').hide();
            $('.dda').hide();
            break;
    }
}


var classes = ["dda","dda","dda","sav","sav","mtg","mtg"];
//Append Header
function appendHeader() {
    var thead = '';
    thead += "<tr class='text-primary text-center'>";
    thead += '<th>Day</th>';
    thead += '<th class="'+classes[0]+'">(dda)Type 400</th>';
    thead += '<th class="'+classes[1]+'">(dda)Type 4044</th>';
    thead += '<th class="'+classes[2]+'">(dda)Type 4045</th>';
    thead += '<th class="'+classes[3]+'">(sav)Type 300</th>';
    thead += '<th class="'+classes[4]+'">(sav)Type 310</th>';
    thead += '<th class="'+classes[5]+'">(mtg)Type 700</th>';
    thead += '<th class="'+classes[6]+'">(mtg)Type 710</th>';
    thead += '</tr>';
    thead += '';

    $('#dataTableHead').append(thead);
}
function appendBody(amountOfDayEnds) {
    var data = "";
    console.log(amountOfDayEnds);
    for(var i=1;i<=amountOfDayEnds;i++) {
        data += '<tr align="center" class="hover-table">';
        data += '<td>' + i + '</td>';
        for (var j = 0; j< 7;j++) {
            data += '<td class="'+classes[j]+'td">' + '<input class="text-center config-input amountOfAccounts" type="number" value="0" min="0" max="500" name="dataAccounts[]" data-error="Please, insert a value"  required></td>'
        }
        data += '</tr>';
    }
    $('#dataTableBody').append(data);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="$('.dda').hide(); $('.ddatd').hide();">HIDE DDA</button>
<table id="dataTable"><thead id="dataTableHead"></thead><tbody id="dataTableBody"></tbody></table>
```